# How to keep the setup for QuarkusIntegrationTest/Native image testing running to develop test efficently?

Tags: testing, quarkus, quarkusintegrationtest

I just set up our first `@QuarkusIntegrationTest`. Now I want to write test against my api.

At the moment, I have to write a test, then run the whole lot (including start of dev services and test resources and the container image under test) to verify the test. This obviously takes quite a while and might be not most efficient way.

Is there a way to start up a `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` test environemnt, including dev services, QuarkusTestResource and container under test, and keep it running without automatically running the test, so I can then write and run my just-written test independently against the running environment?

Comment: Nope, there is way to do this currently, but you can certainly open an issue asking for this feature.

Comment: @geoand I'll do that. Thanks